# Laravel Custom Admin Authentication Not Working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-authentication, laravel-authorization, laravel-admin

I am trying to make a seperate custom admin login in laravel. Everything worked except when i login in from admin login even though the password and email is correct the if conditon is not executed in AdminLoginController.php inside app/Http/auth. It just keep refreshing to the admin login page bascially using the else command return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember')); . Can someone tell me how i can fix this problem.

My Admin.php file inside app folder:

```
    <?php

    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
    use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

    class Admin extends Authenticatable
    {
    use Notifiable;

    protected $guard = 'admin';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
     ];
 }
```

My AdminController.php file inside app/Http/Controllers folder:

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    class AdminController extends Controller
    {
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:admin');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('admin');
    }
 }
```

AdminLoginController.php file inside app/Http/Controllers/Auth folder:

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Auth;

    class AdminLoginController extends Controller
    {
    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->middleware('guest:admin');
    }

    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('auth.admin-login');
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        //  Validate the form data
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email'    => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|min:6'
        ]);
        //  Attempt to log the user in-
        if(Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' =>   $request->password], $request->remember)) {
            //  If sucessfull,then redirect to intended location
            return redirect()->intended(route('admin.dashboard'));
        }
        //  If unsucessfull, then redirect back to the login with the form data
        return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));
    }
 }
```

My auth.php file inside config folder:

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session", "token"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],

        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],

        'admin-api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'admins',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Admin::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
        'admins' => [
            'provider' => 'admins',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
        
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Confirmation Timeout
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define the amount of seconds before a password confirmation
    | times out and the user is prompted to re-enter their password via the
    | confirmation screen. By default, the timeout lasts for three hours.
    |
    */

    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

Admin Migration Table file inside database/migrations:

```
    <?php

    use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
    use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

    class CreateAdminTable extends Migration
    {
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('admins', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('admins');
    }
  }
```

My admin.blade.php file inside resources/views:

```
    @extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">ADMIN {{ __('Dashboard') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    @if (session('status'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                            {{ session('status') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif

                    {{ __('You are logged in!') }} as <strong>ADMIN</strong>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

My admin-login.blade.php file inside resources/views/auth:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">ADMIN {{ __('Login') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('admin.login.submit') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email" autofocus>

                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="current-password">

                                @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}>

                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="remember">
                                        {{ __('Remember Me') }}
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Login') }}
                                </button>

                                @if (Route::has('password.request'))
                                    <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                                        {{ __('Forgot Your Password?') }}
                                    </a>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

my web.php file inside routes folder:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::prefix('admin')->group(function() {
    Route::get('/login', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@showLoginForm')->name('admin.login');
    Route::post('/login', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@login')->name('admin.login.submit');
    Route::get('/', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin.dashboard');
});
```

Yes it is pointing to the admin.blade.php file in views as in image below:
[image]

Comment: You seem to have a middleware, would you mind sharing that one? Your middleware might be failing.

Comment: @killstreet do you mean my Authenticate.php in Middleware folder? or what do you mean

Comment: You have a middleware in your admin controller in the constructor. I don't see anything else wrong with any of the code so I'm expecting the middleware doing something.

Comment: @killstreet can you look in the above image the middleware  is showing to the admin.blade.php file.

Comment: `if(Auth::guard('admin')->check()) {
    dd("admin");
} elseif (Auth::guard('web')->check())
    dd("web");
}`

Comment: Can you add some like this code before if-else condition in login method inside `AdminLoginController`?

Comment: in __construct() function or where?

Comment: in `login` method ` inside `AdminLoginController`. Before `if(Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email'`...` this condition

Comment: @Alex no it did not work just like before even after entering correct credentials it reloads the page after pressing login

Comment: It looks like the middleware is causing this problem. The uploaded image shows the file it returns at the end which isn't very use full. Could you add the code of the admin:auth middleware you are calling in the AdminController constructor?

Comment: @killstreet there was a spelling mistake so it was causing the problem i fixed it.